# Convert Static method in Dagger Module class to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have following project in Github : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/TMDb-Paging which I use Dagger2 for dependency injection.

One of my `Module` classes is as Follow in java :

```
@Module
public abstract class DetailModule {

    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract DetailFragment detailFragment();

    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    static Movie provideMovie(DetailActivity activity) {
        return activity.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_MOVIE);
    }
}
```

As you can see `provideMovie` method is `static`. When I convert it to Kotlin :

```
@Module
abstract class DetailModule {

    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun detailFragment(): DetailFragment

    companion object {

        @Provides
        @ActivityScoped
        internal fun provideMovie(activity: DetailActivity): Movie {
            return activity.intent.extras.getParcelable(EXTRA_MOVIE)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I build the project I get following Kotlin compiler error :

```
error: @Provides methods can only be present within a @Module or @ProducerModule
        public final com.sample.android.tmdb.vo.Movie provideMovie$app_debug(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Could be any solution to have the class in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Comanion Object` is technically different class and not annotated with `@Module`. (So you are getting that error)

you need to use JVM Annotations for methods. So Kotlin will create a static method inside `DetailModule` itself.

Try `@JvmStatic`

```
@Module
    companion object {
         @JvmStatic
         @Provides
         @ActivityScoped
         internal fun provideMovie(activity: DetailActivity): Movie {
             return activity.intent.extras.getParcelable(EXTRA_MOVIE)
         }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try annotating `Companion Object` with `@Module` ? I have updated the answer.

Comment: So what was happening is that - `@JvmStatic` indeed adds a static method `provideMovie` to `DetailModule` itself. But `companion class` will also contains same method with `@Provides` annotation that was causing this issue since `companion class` is not a `Module`. Adding `@Module` to `companion object` will make this error go away.